# Java 1.7 GregorianCalendar computes wrong date

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I am having problems with Java 1.7's GregorianCalender. I know moving to Java 8 or using Joda might resolve my problem but unfortunately this is not an option.

So I am trying to add 365 days to calculate an end date (it might seem stupid to add 365 days and not just add a year but that is what my client requested and even after asking him many times he wants to stick with it, because he wants to ignore leap years).

In general all is working well, but in the following unit test it fails his and my expectation. I recalculated it a few times now and used various tools to check my results but I just can not confirm java's calculation.

Here is my unit test that will fail, because it returns a wrong date:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    // Get a Gregorian Calendar
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

    // Remove whatever was stored previously
    cal.clear();

    // Set calendar to 2004-10-23
    cal.set( 2004, Calendar.OCTOBER, 23 );

    // Add 365 days
    cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 365 );

    // Calendar should be at 2005-10-22 now
    Assert.assertEquals( 2005, cal.get( Calendar.YEAR ) );
    Assert.assertEquals( Calendar.OCTOBER, cal.get( Calendar.MONTH ) );
    Assert.assertEquals( 22, cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) );
}
```

It will fail with:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<22> but was:<23>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You go from *October* 2004 to October 2005. There is no leap day in between, therefore the day of the month is still the 23rd. Now, if you were to start at 2003-10-23 that'd be different.